# Terraform / Terragrunt remove state does not actually remove state

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

I accidentally created a Terraform state resource `aws_security_group.db_security_group`. It was created from a aborted attempt to rename resources. However, in my HCL file itself, the resource definiion is

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sandbox_db_security_group" {
  name                    = "${var.sg_name}"
  vpc_id                  = "${var.sg_vpc_id}"
}
```

I'd like to delete this state from Terraform management. So first, I listed my state:

```
[terragrunt] 2019/12/02 09:10:12 Running command: terraform state list
aws_security_group.db_security_group
aws_security_group.sandbox_db_security_group
```

Then I remove the state:

```
[terragrunt] 2019/12/02 09:13:26 Running command: terraform state rm aws_security_group.db_security_group
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
1 items removed.
Item removal successful.
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
```

However, if I then run the same state list command, I see that my resource is still there:

```
[terragrunt] 2019/12/02 09:14:52 Running command: terraform state list
aws_security_group.db_security_group
aws_security_group.sandbox_db_security_group
```

When I show the resource, nothing appears:

```
    [terragrunt] 2019/12/02 09:17:34 Running command: terraform state show aws_security_group.db_security_group

**NO OUTPUT**
```

When I show `aws_security_group.sandbox_db_security_group`, I do get the expected security group resource information.

More worringly, when I run `terragrunt plan`, I get a panic:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x1813b38]

goroutine 702 [running]:
github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform.(*NodeRefreshableManagedResourceInstance).evalTreeManagedResourceNoState(0xc000328308, 0x30, 0x2255780)
        /private/tmp/terraform@0.11-20190523-67936-10xg42a/terraform-0.11.14/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform/node_resource_refresh.go:238 +0x328
github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform.(*NodeRefreshableManagedResourceInstance).EvalTree(0xc000328308, 0x234b640, 0xc000328308)
        /private/tmp/terraform@0.11-20190523-67936-10xg42a/terraform-0.11.14/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform/node_resource_refresh.go:98 +0x6e
github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform.(*Graph).walk.func1(0x234b640, 0xc000328308, 0x0, 0x0)
        /private/tmp/terraform@0.11-20190523-67936-10xg42a/terraform-0.11.14/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform/graph.go:113 +0x94d
github.com/hashicorp/terraform/dag.(*Walker).walkVertex(0xc000369b90, 0x234b640, 0xc000328308, 0xc0002e2240)
        /private/tmp/terraform@0.11-20190523-67936-10xg42a/terraform-0.11.14/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/dag/walk.go:387 +0x33b
created by github.com/hashicorp/terraform/dag.(*Walker).Update
        /private/tmp/terraform@0.11-20190523-67936-10xg42a/terraform-0.11.14/src/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/dag/walk.go:310 +0xa4f

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! TERRAFORM CRASH !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

I suspect that this is a result of this resource, which doesn't actually exist but still has some memory reference in Terraform's DAG. In any case,how do I actually remove this darn resource?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove all temporary terraform/terragrunt downloads,
inspect the state manually (you probably store it on s3),
if necessary, remove/edit manually on s3 (requires dynamodb entry edit),
re-run terragrunt init and then plan.